# jquery-ui dialog display close icon and wrong text

Tags: jquery-ui

jquery-ui dialog display close icon and "close" wrong text..

jquery Ui version 1.12.1 and code:

```
function callDialog() {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        closeOnEscape: false, resizable: false, height: "auto", width: 400, modal: true, buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close"); },
            "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close"); }
         }
    });
}
```

How to fix it
[image]

Comment: This may be related to CSS. Please provide more details about your current code and jQuery UI version and theme.

Comment: jquery Ui version 1.12.1 and code: function callDialog() {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            closeOnEscape: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: "auto",
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "No": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }

Comment: Have you found any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 8):

I've solved this adding closeText (see the last line):

```js
  $('#dialog').dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   width: 500,
   height:500,
   resizable: true,
   title: 'Items',
   modal: true,
   open: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).load("@Url.Action("StorageItemListPartial", "StorageItem")");
   },
   buttons: {
    "Close": function () {
     $(this).dialog("close");
    }
   },
   closeText: ''
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

I had this same error and correct it by changing the following line of code closeText: "Close" for closeText: "" in jquery-ui file

```
$.widget( "ui.dialog", {
version: "1.12.1",
options: {
    appendTo: "body",
    autoOpen: true,
    buttons: [],
    classes: {
        "ui-dialog": "ui-corner-all",
        "ui-dialog-titlebar": "ui-corner-all"
    },
    closeOnEscape: true,
    closeText: "",
```